# Pop all dataframes from a list of Dataframes

Tags: python

I have a list of dataframes
`list_df = [df1,df2,df3,df4]`

I want to loop this list and pop all contained df's, something like:

`for df in list_df:`
        `list_df.pop(df)`

So after required code I will have 4 new dataframes df1,df2,df3,df4.

Comment: you want to save all dataframes in one dataframe right?

Comment: No i want new df's of all dfs in list. If list of df has 10 df I want to create 10 new df's

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Can't you simply reassign the variables? `df1, df2, df3, df4 = list_df`

Comment: @alec_djinn It's a long list of 1000+ dfs, Would not be feasible to write all variable names.

Comment: @NaiveBayes I see. But then please, specify it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_df = [df1,df2,df3]

for i in range(0,len(list_df)):
    globals()['cf%s' % i] = list_df[i]

print(cf0)
print(cf1)
print(cf2)
```

Comment: Can you explain this code please?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new list:

```
new_list = []
for df in list_df:
    df = ...
    new_list.append(df)
```

Comment: Sorry but I am tring to output new dataframes from a list of dataframes. Your code just gives a list of df's again like my original list. Like if my list = [df1,df2,df3]. I need to loop this list and instantiate these df as new dfs. So after code I will have 3 new dfs.